# C# ElasticSeach Mock Suggestions

Tags: elasticsearch, moq

I am trying to mock a suggest response, however `suggestionOption.Setup(x => x.Text).Returns("Hello")` is throwing an exception:

> An exception of type `System.NotSupportedException` occurred in
>   Moq.dll but was not handled in user code Additional information:
>   Invalid setup on a non-virtual (overridable in VB) member: x => x.Text

---

```
       var searchSuggestResponseMock = new Mock<ISuggestResponse>();

        var suggestionOption = new Mock<SuggestOption>();
        suggestionOption.Setup(x => x.Text).Returns("Hello");
        suggestionOption.Setup(x => x.Payload).Returns("{path:\"drugs/hello\"}");

        var suggestion = new Mock<Suggest>();
        suggestion.Setup(x => x.Options).Returns(new List<SuggestOption> { suggestionOption.Object });

        searchSuggestResponseMock.Setup(x => x.Suggestions).Returns(new Dictionary<string, Suggest[]>()
        {
              {"suggest", new Suggest[] {suggestion.Object}},
        });

        var mock = new Mock<IConnector>();
        mock.Setup(x => x.getClient()
            .Suggest<Term>(Moq.It.IsAny<Func<SuggestDescriptor<Term>,
            SuggestDescriptor<Term>>>())).Returns(searchSuggestResponseMock.Object);

        _connector = mock.Object;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't mock non-virtual methods.  As the error states:

```
Invalid setup on non-virtual member
```

Moq does its magic by acting as a proxy between your code and the real class.  It does this by taking advantage of virtual methods.  Without having a virtual method, Moq can't intercept the call.

Comment: Thanks Patrick, what are my options in that case? Just to have my tests call an Elastic instance instead?

Answer (score 1):

Neither SuggestionOption, or Suggest are easily mockable, as they have non-virtual, internal set based properties, and do not implement any specific interface.

It looks like you are maybe mocking at too low a level. If you don't want to call Elastic to get your list of suggestions then have a method which just returns an array of strings (or your own custom Suggestion class) and mock that instead.

Or just call Elastic for real, as long as you are passing in sensible values which don't return thousands of suggestions.

(Or you could in theory create instances of Suggest, and set the internal properties via reflection, but this is not ideal obviously).